Android Credentials Google Sign In Error: [16] Account reauth failed
Following the android guidelines to integrate Google Sign in with credentials api 
Google Sign in with credentials manager
val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)
val googleIdOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption = 
GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder("web-client-id here")
  .build()
val request: GetCredentialRequest = 
GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
  .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
  .build()
coroutineScope.launch {
 try {
     val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
         request = request,
         context = context,
     )
     handleGoogleLoginResult(result)
 } catch (t: Throwable) {
     Log.d(TAG, t.message.toString())
 }
 }

I receive this error:
[16] Account reauth failed.

with type
GetCredentialException.TYPE_USER_CANCELED

The weird part is that in a test project this works with the same keys. 
Anyone has encountered this issue before? 
Note i use this in KMM project and compose
Edit: 31/07/2024 
I found a solution 
I had provided wrong sha-1 in google credentials. My project has a lot of modules so i accidentaly provided the sha-1 of another module

Same problem here: https://github.com/android/identity-samples/issues/90

GetCredentialException.TYPE_USER_CANCELED  is the error type value for when the user intentionally cancelled the request.

@Bob this is not exactly true. When user indeed cancel the request (by clicking outside the dialog or press back) then i get the same error type but the error message says "[16] Cancelled by user." . Now i get another error message as you can see

@PanosMakris It may be true but as per documentation you can see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/credentials/GetCredentialException

How long did it take to propagate? I'm experiencing the same issue...

@Panos I have the same issue, I checked and found that I have already the SHA-1 key for the App signing key certificate, and it's already there in the android client id on Google Cloud Console. Could you guide me where did you set the SHA-1? and btw, in my case in release build it works something and sometimes not!

If you are testing your app from Internal App Sharing on Play Console (which is different from Internal track), then you need to get the SHA-1 form there and create a new Client Id on Google Cloud Console.

In my case, this issue was happening because I was using a testing project (instead of trying to implement it directly on my game), and this testing project I created with a different package name than the one used in the Google Cloud (Android Client Id).
I'm pretty sure the different SHA-1 was also an issue, but I started using the real project keystore in my testing project when trying to find the reason for [16] Account reauth failed. and have not tested again without the keystore.
